# Using a private variable in a controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm developing a website using CodeIgniter.

I have declared a controller, in this controller class I added a private variable as an array, and I filled this array with informations from the session class.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Admin extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct()
    {
        private $data  = Array('');

        parent::__construct();
        $this->data = Array(
            'nom' => $this->session->userdata('admin_fullname')
        );
    }
```

In some methods I have to call this variable as:

```
public function dashboard(){
    $this->load->view('admin/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('admin/left_navigation');
    $this->load->view('admin/dashboard');
    $this->load->view('admin/footer');
}
```

But it gives me this error :

> #A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined
>   variable: data Filename: controllers/admin.php Line Number: 73

The line number 73 is : `$this->load->view('admin/header', $data);`

Comment: `$data` -> `$this->data`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're declaring the private variable within a function; you'll have to move it to class level and initialize it inside the construct or function.

So this:

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller{

  public function __construct()
  {
    private $data  = Array('');

    parent::__construct();
    $this->data = Array(
        'nom' => $this->session->userdata('admin_fullname')
      );
  }
```

Will turn into this:

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller{

  private $data;
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->data  = Array('');

    parent::__construct();
    $this->data = Array(
        'nom' => $this->session->userdata('admin_fullname')
      );
  }
```

Also, don't forget to access your data array by prefixing it with `$this->`.

Comment: Slight syntax error. `$this->$data  = Array('');` should be: `$this->data  = Array('');` (or, preferably, `$this->data  = array();`).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using an object attribute, you need to prefix it with `$this`:

```
$this->load->view('admin/header', $this->data);
```

Also, you should declare it in the class scope, not in the constructor's.